# Creation of Python unit test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

function_one.py

```
class FunctionOne(Base):
    def __init__(self, amount, tax):
        super().__init__(amount, tax)
```

function_two.py

```
Class FunctionTwo:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.__a = a
        self.__b = b
        self.__c = c

    def _get_info(self):
        x = FunctionOne(0, 1)
        return x
```

test_function_two.py

```
class TestPostProcessingStrategyFactory(unittest.TestCase):
    def test__get_info(self):
        a = “a”
        b = “b”
        c = “c”
        amount = 0
        tax = 1

        function_two = FunctionTwo(a, b, c)

        assert function_two.__get_info() == FunctionOne(0,1)
```

I am trying to create unit test for the function_two.py source code. I get the assertion error that the object at ******** != object at *********.
So the two objects address is different. How can make this test pass by correcting the assert statement

```
assert function_two.__get_info() == FunctionOne(0,1)
```

Comment: You are kind of mixing methods from `unittest` and `pytest` in here. Are you using pytest for testing?, then you dont have to create a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`.

Comment: This is the second question of yours I've seen where you don't react in any way to the provided answer. If it doesn't help you/solve your problem, you can at least comment on it and explain why. If it _does_ help, consider at least marking it as accepted.

Comment: I am not aware of that, sorry for that. Will add it for the previous as well now!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that **equality** comparisons depend on the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method of a class. From the code you provided it appears that simply initializing two objects of `FunctionOne` with the same arguments does not result in two objects that compare as **equal**. Whatever implementation of `__eq__` underlies that class, only you know that.

However, I would argue the approach is faulty to begin with because **unit** tests, as the name implies, are supposed to isolate your units (i.e. **functions** typically) as much as possible, which is not what you are doing here.

When you are testing a function `f` that calls another of *your* functions `g`, strictly speaking, the correct approach is mocking `g` during the test. You need to ensure that you are testing `f` **and only** `f`. This extends to instances of other classes that you wrote, since their methods are also just functions that you wrote.

Have a look at the following example `code.py`:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        ...


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.__a = a
        self.__b = b

    def get_foo(self):
        foo = Foo(self.__a, self.__b)
        return foo
```

Say we want to test `Bar.get_foo`. That method uses *our* `Foo` class inside it, instantiating it and returning that instance. We want to ensure that this is what the method does. We **don't** want to concern ourselves with anything that relates to the implementation of `Foo` because that is for another test case.

What we need to do is mock that class entirely. Then we substitute some unique object to be returned by calling our mocked `Foo` and check that we get that object from calling `get_foo`.

In addition, we want to check that `get_foo` called the (mocked) `Foo` constructor with the arguments we expected, i.e. with its `__a` and `__b` attributes.

Here is an example `test.py`:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from . import code


class BarTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch.object(code, "Foo")
    def test_get_foo(self, mock_foo_cls: MagicMock) -> None:
        # Create some random but unique object that should be returned,
        # when the mocked class is called;
        # this object should be the output of `get_bar`:
        mock_foo_cls.return_value = expected_output = object()
        # We remember the arguments to initialize `bar` for later:
        a, b = "spam", "eggs"
        bar = code.Bar(a=a, b=b)
        # Run the method under testing:
        output = bar.get_foo()
        # Check that we get that EXACT object returned:
        self.assertIs(expected_output, output)
        # Ensure that our mocked class was instantiated as expected:
        mock_foo_cls.assert_called_once_with(a, b)
```

That way we ensure proper isolation from our `Foo` class during the `Bar.get_foo` test.

Side note: If we wanted to be super pedantic, we should even isolate our test method from the initialization of `Bar`, but in this simple example that would be overkill. If your `__init__` method does many things aside from just setting some instance attributes, you should definitely mock that during your test as well.

Hope this helps.

**References:**

- The [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) class
- The [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) decorator
- [`TestCase.assertIs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIs)
- [`Mock.assert_called_once_with`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once_with)